# How can I append Form text to a URL in JQuery, in the following example:

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, url, append

I've seen a few similar posts, but nothing explains a method which fits into my example.

I'm looking to take what has been typed into a Form with the ID "searchbox", and append it to the following script:

Form:

```
    <form method="get"> 
    <span><input type="text" class="search rounded" placeholder="Search..." id='searchbox' autofocus></span>
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){

$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){

    var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var appendedText=  $(this).val();

    $('ul > li > a').each(function(){
        var currentLiText = $(this).attr('class')
        showCurrentLi = currentLiText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
        $(this).toggle(showCurrentLi);

        if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
            chrome.tabs.create({url:'http://www.exampletestsite.com/'+appendText});
            return false;
        }
        return true;           
    });     
});
```

Most of the code simply filters a list of preset options, pressing enter will load the url appended with the typed text instead of using a clickable preset.

I'm trying to set the 'appendedtext' variable to get what has been typed into the search field, and on Enter press, load a URL with the appended text.

I thought this var would work, but it doesn't:

```
    var appendedText= $('#searchbox').val();
```

I'm pretty sure I'm just an idiot though, since this seems incredibly simple. Any help would be really appreciated.

EDIT: Added form format for clarity. Fixed code snippet, added some information about the code.

Comment: where is `event` coming from? try passing it to the anonymous function: ... `.keyup(function(event){` ...

Comment: @vch I accidentally pasted an incorrect code before, this is the full snippet which works if plain text is used in place of the appendText variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my issue was with the `$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){`, specifically 'keyup'. Keyup would clear my searchbox content by default before sending the data which appended to the url. I merely changed it to keydown and everything worked perfectly.

Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The line `var appendedText= $('#searchbox').val();` works perfectly well, as you can see in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tn0fhn27/1/) fiddle (passing the event parameter isn't necessary, and certainly isn't the root of the problem).  However, I got rid of the form and span elements, and the chrome.tabs stuff, so I suspect your issue lies in one of those.

I'm not sure how to help if that's not the actual problem, but as far as jQuery and `.val()` go, everything's fine.